# 1 of the RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView doesn't load at the start of the activity

Tags: android, firebase

I have three recycler View inside the Nested Scroll View when the activity is started it doesn't load first recycler View. I have swipe Refresh Layout in app when I refresh all the recycler View are loaded properly. The second recycler view doesn't load at the start of the activity tried every solution.

Java File

```
shops.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot photosnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Shops temp=photosnapshot.getValue(Shops.class);
                    Location templocation=new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    Location templocation1=new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    templocation.setLatitude(temp.getAddress().getLatitude());
                    templocation.setLongitude(temp.getAddress().getLongitude());
                    templocation1.setLatitude(common.currentLocation.getLatitude());
                    templocation1.setLongitude(common.currentLocation.getLongitude());
                    if(templocation.distanceTo(templocation1)<1500)
                    {
                        shopslist.add(new Shops(temp.getName(),temp.getImage(),temp.getStatus(),temp.getTimings(),temp.getAddress(),photosnapshot.getKey(),temp.getCategory()));
                        if(temp.getCategory().equals("02"))
                        {
                            dairyshoplist.add(new Shops(temp.getName(),temp.getImage(),temp.getStatus(),temp.getTimings(),temp.getAddress(),photosnapshot.getKey(),temp.getCategory()));
                        }



                    }
                }
                menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



recyclemenu= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recyclecategory=findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu_categories);
        headerusername= (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.textnameheader);
        headerusername.setText(common.currentuser.getName());
        recyclemenu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclecategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
        recyclemenu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclecategory.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        recycle_dairy_shops.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
        recycle_dairy_shops.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclemenu.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recycle_dairy_shops.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclecategory.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

.xml File

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.mahesh.door_step.Home"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"

        >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menu_categories"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/recycler_menu"
    android:fillViewport="true"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_menu_categories"
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menu_dairyshops"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nearbyshopid"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: `scrollview` has weird behavior when you use `layout_height="match_parent"` . Try to change the `layout_height` from `NestedScrollView` to `wrap_content `

Comment: I don't see any line where you put data in recyclerview?